# How to replace groups of characters between flags in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, char, flags

Suppose I have a char variable in Matlab like this:

```
x = 'hello ### my $ name is Sean Daley.';
```

I want to replace the first '###' with the char '&', and the first '$' with the char '&&'.

Note that the character groups I wish to swap have different lengths [e.g., length('###') is 3 while length('&') is 1].

Furthermore, if I have a more complicated char such that pairs of '###' and '$' repeat many times, I want to implement the same swapping routine. So the following:

```
y = 'hello ### my $ name is ### Sean $ Daley ###.$.';
```

would be transformed into:

```
'hello & my && name is & Sean && Daley &.&&.'
```

I have tried coding this (for any arbitrary char) manually via for loops and while loops, but the code is absolutely hideous and does not generalize to arbitrary character group lengths.

Are there any simple functions that I can use to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
y = replace(y,["###" "$"],["&"  "&&"])
```

Comment: It’s useful if you include a link to the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/replace.html

Comment: Strings with double quotes in an array only work in versions beginning with R2017a. Prior to R2017a you need to use cell arrays instead, like `y = replace(y, {'###' '$'}, {'&'  '&&'})`.

Answer (score 2):

The function [strrep](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: For one instance yes, but this is not a general solution. I'm guessing the general solution would include instances of strrep.

Comment: @SeanDaley: you would have to call `strrep` twice, once for each replacement pattern. It does replace all occurrences of the pattern.